# Form calculator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make a form for my website where I can calculate the cost of a rewire for a customer. I have done the HTML elements but I am struggling to do the javascript.

What I want to show is:

```
<b>
<form id="rewire" action="">
  <p>Occupancy<br />
   Empty<input type="radio" name="occupancy" value="empty" /><br /> 
    Occupied<input type="radio" name="occupancy" value="livedin" /><br />
    <br />
Type of property
<br />
    <select name="property">
        <option value="bungalow">Bungalow</option>
        <option value="terraced">Terraced</option>
        <option value="detached">Semi / Detached</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
Number of rooms
<br />
Bedrooms
<br />
    <select name="bedrooms">
        <option value="1bed">1</option>
        <option value="2bed">2</option>
        <option value="3bed">3</option>
        <option value="4bed">4</option>
        <option value="5bed">5</option>
        <option value="6bed">6</option>
        <option value="7bed">7</option>
        <option value="8bed">8</option>
    </select>
        <br /><br />
Living Rooms
<br />
    <select name="Livingrooms">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
            <br /><br />
Bathrooms
<br />
    <select name="bathrooms">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
            <br /><br />
Kitchens
<br />
    <select name="Kitchens">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
            <br /><br />
Dining Rooms
<br />
    <select name="Diningrooms">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</b>
```

I want the calculator to add up seperate elements from the form. For example:-

> Each bedroom adds a cost of £210
>   Each living room £270
>   each Bathroom £305
>   each kithen £470
>   each dining room £210
>
> if it is lived in + £250
>
> terraced + £250
>   terraced + attic £350
>
> +£340 for standard costs hidden from the form.

Comment: I tried using a template from another calc based script but just completely messed it up. If someone could explain how to do one of the elements I could probably work it out from that. :-)

Comment: 1) find form element 2) get its value 3) multiply it by the cost/per one 4) add to total.

Comment: and use real numbers for your bedroom values. `8bed` makes me want to cry.

Comment: Can you give me a code example for the first element please? @jpaugh

Comment: I used 8bed because I didn't want it to clash with other elements...I am a complete noob with javascript but want to give it a bash!

Comment: I don't actually remember the specifics of javascript. (I use google for my js projects.) But each of my 4 steps is a common programming problem for js. You can definitely find code on sites like Mozilla's Dev Center. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: btw, the name and value are combined when the form is processed, like `bedroom=8bed`, so there's no conflict.

Comment: Post what you have already tried with js. Then, we can help you clean it up so that it works flawlessly. This form calculation is basic js programming. It's simple. And you will learn a lot if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ID onto each form element so they are easier to target with javascript. For instance:

```
<select name="property" id="property">
```

I also highly recommend including jQuery which makes getting the value from different form elements much easier. If you do that, then the javascript will be something like:

```
function calc(){
    total = 340;
    total += $("#livingroom").val() * 270;
    //etc

}
```

Comment: dont forget <script src = "jquery.js">

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 1bed,2bed etc. You should use 1,2 etc. as  values.

HTML codes must be nearly this:

```
    <select name="property">
    <option name="bungalow" value="itscost(ex:110$)">Bungalow</option>
    <option name="terraced" value"itscost">Terraced</option>
    <option name="detached" value"itscost">Semi / Detached</option>
    </select>
<select name="bedrooms">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
 var abc = $("select[name=property] option:selected").val();
 var def = $("select[name=bedrooms] option:selected").val();
 //each bedroom 210$
 var bedroomscost = def * 20;
 var total = abc + bedroomcost + livingroomcost.... etc. ;
```

You should make as these. I hope I could tell well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a calculator for your website I would suggest you to take a look at “Appizy”.

It converts instantly a spreadsheet into a standalone web calculation tool in HTML and JAVASCRIPT. You don’t need to hardcode the whole interface and calculation formulas!

Just create your working calculator with Open- or LibreOffice and then use Appizy.

I hope it can help. Best,
Nicolas